# JavaFX: How to make a Table Cell to be contigent to the value of another Table Cell

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a very simple model composed of 3 `StringProperty`, let's call them `property1`, `property2` and `property3`. I have defined the usual `get/set/property` methods in my model. I'm now using a `TableView` to display some of these properties. The Column model is defined as follow

```
TableColumn<MyModel, String> tableColumn1 = new TableColumn<MyModel, String>("display 1");
TableColumn<MyModel, String> tableColumn2 = new TableColumn<MyModel, String>("display 2");
```

now the TableColumn follow the pattern of using a cell value factory linked to one of the property of my model.

```
tableColumn1.setCellValueFactory((t)-> {
                MyModel myModelValue  = ((MyModel)t.getValue());    
                return myModelValue.getProperty3().equals("something") ? property1():property2();
            });

tableColumn2.setCellValueFactory((t)-> property3());
```

The problem is now the following. If `property3` is changed somewhere during the execution, it will correctly trigger a change in the column2 of my table and an UI update of the cell. But it won't do anything for column1 as neither `property1` and `property2` have changed. How can I somehow force the column1 to change or listen contingently to the change of `property3`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableColumn1.setCellValueFactory(t -> {
    MyModel myModelValue = t.getValue();
    return Bindings.when(myModelValue.property3().equals("something"))
        .then(myModelValue.property1())
        .otherwise(myModelValue.property2());
});
```

Comment: Well, you have to admit that java has become really neat ! Thanks, beautiful answer, I had forgotten this `when` binding feature